# Deriving "quasi-theta" functions from theta functions' zeros

Tags: theta-functions, zeroes

I've been trying to sift the zeros of \begin{align}\vartheta(z)&=e^{-\pi z^2}\prod_{k\ge1}(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z})\\
&=\prod_{k\ge1}(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z})\end{align}
raised to a power of $z$ (viz. $\vartheta^{z^n}(z)$), and my approach to the case $n=1$ looks promising...

### Zeros of $\vartheta^z(z)$

Because $\vartheta(z)$ vanishes at $k+im$ for all half-integers $k,m$, $\;\vartheta^z(z)$ will have zeros of degree $k+im$. But the degrees can be split by sign, so the zeros can be stated to have degrees $k^+$ and/or $im^+$, and also *poles* of like order.

So, namely, the zeros $k^+\!\pm im^+$ will have multiplicity $k^+$, and $-k^+\!\pm im^+$ are poles of order $k^+$; $\pm k^+\!+im^+$ will contribute zeros of degree $im^+$, and $\pm k^+\!-im^+$, *poles* of degree $im^+$.

The $k^+$-degree zeros can be inherited by $\cosh(\pi z-\pi k^+)$ (or better, $1+e^{2\pi z-2k^+\pi}$, to create a convergent product); similarly, the $im^+$-degree zeros are satisfied by $1+e^{-2i\pi z-2\pi m^+}$. Additionally, the poles are covered by $(1+e^{-2\pi z-2k^+\pi})^{-k^+}(1+e^{2i\pi z-2m^+\pi})^{-im^+}$.

Thus $\vartheta^z(z)$ can be written as$$P(z)\prod_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{1+e^{2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1+e^{-2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{k-1/2}\bigg(\frac{1+e^{-2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1+e^{2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{i(k-1/2)}$$

To find out $P(z)$, I now take the log-derivative...\begin{align}\ln\vartheta(z)+z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)\!=\frac{P'}P(z)+\sum_{k\ge1}\big(k-\tfrac12\big)&\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}+1}-\frac{-2\pi}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}+1}\\
&+i\bigg[\frac{-2i\pi}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z}+1}-\frac{2i\pi}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}+1}\bigg]\bigg)\\[3ex]
=\frac{P'}P(z)+\pi\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg(&\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}+1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}+1}\\
&+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z}+1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}+1}\bigg)
\end{align}
and use the identities\begin{align}\pi\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}+1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}+1}\bigg)=&\frac\pi{12}-\frac1{12\pi}\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0)+\pi z^2\\&+z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)
+\frac1{4\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)\tag1\\[2ex]
\pi\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}+1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z}+1}\bigg)=&\frac\pi{12}+\frac1{12\pi}\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0)-\frac1{4\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)\tag2\end{align}
to solve for $P(z)$:\begin{align}\frac{P'}P(z)&=\ln\vartheta(z)+z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)-\bigg[\frac\pi{12}-\frac1{12\pi}\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0)+\pi z^2+z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)
+\frac1{4\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)\bigg]\\
&\quad-\bigg[\frac\pi{12}+\frac1{12\pi}\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0)-\frac1{4\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)\bigg]\\[1ex]
&=\ln\vartheta(z)-\frac\pi6-\pi z^2\end{align}
$$\ln P(z)=C-\frac{\pi z}6-\frac{\pi z^3}3+\int_A^z\ln\vartheta(t)\,dt$$
$$\ln P(0)=C+\int_A^0\ln\vartheta(t)\,dt$$
$$\ln P(z)-\ln P(0)=-\frac{\pi z}6-\frac{\pi z^3}3+\int_0^z\ln\vartheta(t)\,dt$$
And because\begin{align}\vartheta^0(0)=1&=P(0)\prod_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi}}{1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{k-1/2}\bigg(\frac{1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi}}{1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{i(k-1/2)}\\
&=P(0)\end{align}
I now have
$\boxed{\vartheta^z(z)=e^{-\pi z/6-\pi z^3/3+\int_0^z\ln\vartheta(t)\,dt}\cdot\prod_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{1\!+e^{2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1\!+e^{-2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{\!k-1/2}\bigg(\frac{1\!+e^{-2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1\!+e^{2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{\!i(k-1/2)}}$

I tried using this approach on the cases $n\gt1$, but the zero-products got really messy, and amount of evaluations in the appendix below suggests that further cases will be tedious and unwieldy. Further, I cannot verify any non-trivial values for the boxed formula.

Can anyone help me find a similar product form for $\vartheta^{z^2}(z)$ or higher $z$ powers?

### Appendix

To prove identities $(1)$ and $(2)$, I'll have to use a quotient (double) formula that can be derived with the method of partial fractions:\begin{align}\frac{\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)}{\vartheta(z)\varphi(a)}&=\pi e^{-2a\pi z}\bigg(\operatorname{csch}a\pi+2\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg[\frac{e^{(2k-1)a\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}\!+\!1}-\frac{e^{-(2k-1)a\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}\!+\!1}\bigg]\bigg)\\[1ex]
&=\pi\csc a\pi+2i\pi\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg[\frac{e^{(2k-1)ai\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}\!+\!1}-\frac{e^{-(2k-1)ai\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z}\!+\!1}\bigg]\end{align}
where\begin{align}\varphi(z)&=2e^{-\pi z^2-\pi/4}\sinh\pi z\prod_{k\ge1}(1-e^{-2k\pi+2\pi z})(1-e^{-2k\pi-2\pi z})\\
&=2e^{-\pi/4}\sin\pi z\prod_{k\ge1}(1-e^{-2k\pi+2i\pi z})(1-e^{-2k\pi-2i\pi z})
\end{align}
I now have to isolate the sums, then calculate their derivatives at $a=0$:
\begin{align}2\sum_{k\ge1}D_{a\to0}\bigg(\frac{e^{(2k-1)a\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}\!+\!1}-\frac{e^{-(2k-1)a\pi}}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}\!+\!1}\bigg)&=2\pi\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z}\!+\!1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z}\!+\!1}\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=D_{a\to0}\bigg(e^{2a\pi z}\cdot\frac{\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)}{\pi\varphi(a)\vartheta(z)}-\operatorname{csch}a\pi\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=D_{a\to0}\bigg(e^{2a\pi z}\cdot\frac{\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)}{\pi u(a)\sinh a\pi\cdot\vartheta(z)}-\frac{\pi\vartheta(z)}{\pi\sinh a\pi\cdot\vartheta(z)}\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=D_{a\to0}\bigg(\frac{e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)-\pi u(a)\vartheta(z)}{\pi\varphi(a)\;\vartheta(z)}\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=\frac1{\pi\vartheta(z)}\lim_{a\to0}\bigg[\frac{2\pi ze^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)+e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\vartheta'(z+a)-\pi u'(a)\vartheta(z)}{\varphi(a)}-\frac{e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z+a)-\pi u(a)\vartheta(z)}{\varphi^2(a)}\varphi'(a)\bigg]\\[1ex]
&=\frac1{\pi\vartheta(z)}\lim_{a\to0}\frac1{\varphi^2(a)}\big(2\pi ze^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\varphi(a)\vartheta(z+a)+e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\varphi(a)\vartheta'(z+a)-\pi u'(a)\varphi(a)\vartheta(z)-e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\varphi'(a)\vartheta(z+a)+\pi u(a)\varphi'(a)\vartheta(z)\big)\\[1ex]
&=\frac1{2\pi\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z)}\lim_{a\to0}[\varphi(a)]^{-1}\cdot\\[1ex]
&\quad\big(4\pi^2z^2e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\varphi(a)\vartheta(z+a)+4\pi ze^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)\varphi(a)\vartheta'(z+a)\\[1ex]
&\quad+e^{2a\pi z}\varphi'(0)[\varphi(a)\vartheta''(z+a)-\varphi''(a)\vartheta(z+a)]+\pi\vartheta(z)[u(a)\varphi''(a)-u''(a)\varphi(a)]\big)\\[2ex]
&=\frac1{2\pi\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z)}\bigg(4\pi^2z^2\varphi'(0)\vartheta(z)+4\pi z\varphi'(0)\vartheta'(z)+\varphi'(0)\bigg[\vartheta''(z)-\frac{\varphi'''(0)}{\varphi'(0)}\vartheta(z)\bigg]+\pi\vartheta(z)\bigg[u(0)\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0)-u''(0)\bigg]\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=2\pi z^2+2z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)+\frac1{2\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)-\frac{\varphi'''(0)}{2\pi\varphi'(0)}+\frac{u(0)\varphi'''(0)}{2\varphi'^2(0)}-\frac{u''(0)}{2\varphi'(0)}.\end{align}
Since $\varphi(a)=u(a)\sinh a\pi$ and $$\varphi'(a)=u'(a)\sinh a\pi+\pi u(a)\cosh a\pi$$$$\varphi''(a)=u''(a)\sinh a\pi+2\pi u'(a)\cosh a\pi+\pi^2u(a)\sinh a\pi$$$$\varphi'''(a)=u'''(a)\sinh a\pi+3\pi u''(a)\cosh a\pi+3\pi^2u'(a)\sinh a\pi+\pi^3u(a)\cosh a\pi,$$
the sum can be reduced to $$2\pi z^2+2z\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)+\frac1{2\pi}\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)-\frac1{2\varphi'(0)}\frac1{3\pi}\big[\varphi'''(0)-\pi^2\varphi'(0)\big].$$
The calculations for the other sum are similar and lead to $$-2\pi^2\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z}+1}+\frac{2k-1}{e^{(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}+1}\bigg)=\frac12\frac{\vartheta''}\vartheta(z)-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac16\frac{\varphi'''}{\varphi'}(0).$$
The term "quasi-theta" in this article's title alludes to the functions in [this document](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/az1.pdf).

Comment: The link does not work. Also, could you please formulate a question?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I changed the link, and made it clearer I'm seeking help in my thread.

Comment: Thank you! Your material is very interesting but, in my opinion, this site is not really for seeking help. It is intended to be a Q&A site, which is something different from seeking help I believe. Accordingly, the format is not so much of threads but just that - a question and several answers for the asker to choose from.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yeah, it _is_ more a Q&A site...but perhaps those on this site can verify my boxed formula (I can't check it at the moment). Can you recommend me a site/community for my kind of topic?