# An elliptic function built from a log-theta-function integral?

Tags: theta-functions, periodic-functions, zeroes

I'm studying the apparent ellipticity of $$\Theta(z,a):=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x+z)\,dx)}{\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)},\tag1$$with $a$ is a free parameter and \begin{align}\vartheta(z)&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}e^{-\pi(k+z)^2}\\
&=e^{-\pi z^2}\prod_{k\ge1}(1-e^{-2k\pi})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi+2\pi z})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi-2\pi z})\\
&=\prod_{k\ge1}(1-e^{-2k\pi})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi+2i\pi z})(1+e^{-(2k-1)\pi-2i\pi z}).
\end{align}

$\vartheta(z)$ obeys the functional equations $\vartheta(z+1)=\vartheta(z)$ and $\vartheta(z+i)=e^{\pi-2i\pi z}\vartheta(z)$ which, when applied to $(1)$, give \begin{align}\Theta(z+1,a)&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x\!+\!z\!+\!1)\,dx)}{\vartheta(z\!+\!1)\vartheta(z\!+\!1\!+\!a)}=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x\!+\!a)\,dx)}{\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)}\\
&=\Theta(z,a)
\end{align}and\begin{align}\Theta(z+i,a)&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln[e^{\pi-2i\pi(x+z)}\vartheta(x\!+\!z)]\,dx)}{e^{\pi-2i\pi z}\vartheta(z)\cdot e^{\pi-2i\pi(z+a)}\vartheta(z\!+\!a)}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a(\pi x-i\pi x^2-2i\pi xz)_0^a+\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x\!+\!a)\,dx)}{e^{2\pi-4i\pi z-2ai\pi}\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)}\\[2ex]
&=\frac{\exp(2\pi-2ai\pi-4i\pi z+\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x\!+\!a)\,dx)}{e^{2\pi-4i\pi z-2ai\pi}\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)}\\[2ex]
&=\Theta(z,a),
\end{align}so I figured I'd try to determine $\Theta$'s poles and zeros...

From [my post regarding zeros/poles of theta functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290843/deriving-quasi-theta-functions-from-theta-functions-zeros), \begin{multline}\vartheta^z(z)=e^{-\pi z/6-\pi z^3/3+\int_0^z\ln\vartheta(t)\,dt}\\\cdot\prod_{k\ge1}\bigg(\frac{1\!+e^{2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1\!+e^{-2\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{\!k-1/2}\bigg(\frac{1\!+e^{-2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}{1\!+e^{2i\pi z-(2k-1)\pi}}\bigg)^{\!i(k-1/2)},
\end{multline}and since \begin{align}\Theta(z,a)&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_z^{z+a}\ln\vartheta(x)\,dx)}{\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)}\\
&=\frac1{\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)}\exp\bigg[\frac2a\bigg(\int_0^{z+a}-\int_0^z\bigg)\ln\vartheta(x)\,dx\bigg],
\end{align} $\Theta(z,a)$ should only get poles from $\vartheta(z)$ and $\vartheta(z+a)$. But its zeros aren't so evident, so I'll instead analyze $\eta(z,a):=\Theta(z,a)-\Theta(0,a)$.

Obviously, $\eta$ vanishes at $z=0$, but because it shares $\Theta$'s periods, it should also be $0$ at $\mathbb Z(i)$...

The problem for me now is I can't ascertain the degree of the zeros: if they're simple, then I could write $\eta$ as the form $$A(a)\frac{\varphi(z)\varphi(z+a)}{\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)},$$ where\begin{align}
\varphi(z):&=2e^{-\pi z^2-\pi/4}\sinh\pi z\prod_{k\ge1}(1-e^{-2k\pi})(1-e^{-2k\pi+2\pi z})(1-e^{-2k\pi-2\pi z})\\
&=-ie^{-\pi/4+i\pi z}\vartheta(z\!+\!\tfrac{1+i}2)\\
&=0\forall z\in\mathbb Z(i)
\end{align}(The $\varphi(z+a)$ is due to \begin{align}\eta(z\!-\!a,a)&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x\!+\!z\!-\!a)\,dx)}{\vartheta(z\!-\!a)\vartheta(z)}-\Theta(0,a)\qquad\\[1ex]\tag{$\vartheta(-z)=\vartheta(z)$}
&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(a\!-\!z\!-\!x)\,dx)}{\vartheta(a\!-\!z)\vartheta(-z)}-\Theta(0,a)\\[1ex]\tag{$y=a-x$}
&=\frac{\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(y\!-\!z)\,dy)}{\vartheta(a\!-\!z)\vartheta(-z)}-\Theta(0,a)\\[1ex]
&=\Theta(-z,a)-\Theta(0,a),
\end{align} so $\eta(-a,a)$ will vanish like $\eta(0,a)$.)

(Keep in mind that though $\sqrt{\wp(z)}$ has simple poles (branch cuts are superfluous here), its zeros are in general of *fractional* order, so one can't assert rigorously that $\Theta$ or $\eta$ will vanish equivalently to $\varphi$. Additionally, a function can have a *logarithmic* zero, and so its derivative will yield either a pole or vanish at its differentiated remainder (due to $\lim_{x\to0}x^{a\gt0}\ln x=0$).)

Log-differentiating $\Theta(z,a)$ with respect to $z$ will give $$\frac{\Theta'}\Theta(z,a)=\frac2a\bigg(\ln\vartheta(z+a)-\ln\vartheta(z)\bigg)-\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)-\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z+a).$$ Also, \begin{align}\eta'(z,a)=\Theta'(z,a)=&[\eta(z,a)+\Theta(0,a)]\\[1ex]
&\cdot\bigg(\frac2a\ln\frac{\vartheta(z+a)}{\vartheta(z)}-\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z)-\frac{\vartheta'}\vartheta(z+a)\bigg),\end{align} thus $\eta'(0)=\Theta(0,a)\big[\frac2a\ln[\vartheta(a)/\vartheta(0)]-(\vartheta'/\vartheta)(a)\big]$; so unless the latter expression in brackets vanishes for all $a$, $\eta(z,a)$ looks to vanish **once** at any $z\in\mathbb Z(i)$.

Ultimately, I'm wondering if it's valid to represent $\exp(\tfrac2a\int_0^a\ln\vartheta(x+z)\,dx)$ as $$\Theta(0,a)\vartheta(z)\vartheta(z+a)+A(a)\varphi(z)\varphi(z+a).$$(I used Desmos to graph the case $a=1/\sqrt5$, and [it looks promising](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kayhhlnxn8).)

Comment: OK. The case $a=\sqrt2$ showed considerable deviation, so I'm cautiously skeptical of my derivation.

Comment: @Somos I checked with Wolfram Alpha, and got around $0.8440459$ for both values (to six significant digits).

Comment: @Somos Did you make sure the integrand contained $\ln$? It looks like your findings would otherwise check out; when I computed each function individually, then took the quotient(s), I got nearly equal results.

Comment: @Somos Don't sweat it (it's easy to miss).

As for $Theta(z,a)$, I plugged in some other values for $a$, but then got wildly different outputs, so maybe it doesn't hold for general $a$.

Comment: The trouble with $\ln$ is that it has a singularity at zero and branch cuts from there. This causes problems with the integration.

Comment: @Somos Yeah...I figured the logarithm's contribution would be annihilated by the exponentiation. Can it be fixed?

Comment: You may be correct. I will have to do a lot more careful thinking and more double checking.

Comment: I can define functions similar to $\Theta(z,a)$ and derive interrelations, but I'm struggling to create a straightforward notation for them (I'm open to any suggestion(s)).